# Executing a selector after receiving NSNotification calls my view controller's deinit

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

My view controller's `deinit` function is called each time I receive a NSNotification and execute the corresponding selector!!!
Here's my view controller's code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "initModels", name: "xyz.notification", object: nil)
}

func initModels(){
    print("Received notification to init models")
}

deinit {
    print("De-init view controller")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Each the view controller receives the notification, it executes the "initModels" normally, but then the "deinit" is directly called!
Here's what's get printed on console:

```
Received notification to init models
De-init view controller
```

I checked everything related to multi-threading.
The notification is sent on the main thread, and executed on the main thread.

Comment: Perhaps there's a valid reason your vc is being deallocated (e.g., local variable that references it becoming out of scope) that just happens to occur right after the notification is sent...?

Comment: Also, it is a good practice to have your notification handlers take one parameter of type NSNotification (but I'm not sure of what are the consequencies with your signature).

Answer (score 0):

OH MY!
For a reason I don't know, when the selector name starts with "init" it causes my view controller's `deinit` function to be called!

Here's function names I tried:

- initModels >> calls deinit
- init_models >> calls deinit
- initmodels >> works normally
- initializeModels >> works normally

Comment: Change your print statement to output the memory location of the object invoking the method. I'm wondering if calling your `init*` method is causing the original object to be deinitialized? If this is replicatable in a bare class like you've shown, it may be a bug.